# codingBat repeatEnd using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to understand regex as much as I can, so I came up with this regex-based solution to [codingbat.com `repeatEnd`](http://codingbat.com/prob/p152339):

> Given a string and an int N, return a string made of N repetitions of the last N characters of the string. You may assume that N is between 0 and the length of the string, inclusive.

```
public String repeatEnd(String str, int N) {
  return str.replaceAll(
    ".(?!.{N})(?=.*(?<=(.{N})))|."
      .replace("N", Integer.toString(N)),
    "$1"
  );
}
```

Explanation on its parts:

- `.(?!.{N})`: asserts that the matched character is one of the last N characters, by making sure that there aren't N characters following it.
- `(?=.*(?<=(.{N})))`: in which case, use lookforward to first go all the way to the end of the string, then a nested lookbehind to capture the last N characters into `\1`. Note that this assertion will always be true.
- `|.`: if the first assertion failed (i.e. there are at least N characters ahead) then match the character anyway; `\1` would be empty.
- In either case, a character is always matched; replace it with `\1`.

My questions are:

- Is this technique of nested assertions valid? (i.e. looking behind during a lookahead?)
- Is there a simpler regex-based solution?

---

#### Bonus question

Do `repeatBegin` (as analogously defined).

I'm honestly having troubles with this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice one!  I don't see a way to significantly improve on that regex, although I would refactor it to avoid the needless use of negative logic:

```
".(?=.{N})|.(?=.*(?<=(.{N})))"
```

This way the second alternative is never entered until you reach the final *N* characters, which I think makes the intent a little clearer.

I've never seen a reference that says it's okay to nest lookarounds, but like Bart, I don't see why it wouldn't be.  I sometimes use lookaheads inside lookbehinds to get around limitations on variable-length lookbehind expressions.

---

**EDIT:** I just realized I can simplify the regex quite a bit by putting the alternation inside the lookahead:

```
".(?=.{N}|.*(?<=(.{N})))"
```

By the way, have you considered using `format()` to build the regex instead of `replace()`?

```
return str.replaceAll(
  String.format(".(?=.{%1$d}|.*(?<=(.{%1$d})))", N),
  "$1"
);
```

Comment: +1! Good job! Do check out my answer, though: it uses only 2 assertions, `?=` and `?<=`. Also check out my other regex/codingbat question (`wordEnds`). It just got me a Tumbleweed.

Comment: @Alan: I have used `format`, but I think I prefer `replace` because it makes the regex part more readable, and almost an independent entity; with `format`, you can't just pass around the regex without specifying the arguments to `format` since their order matters. You can also see multiple occurrences more easily (e.g. if there are multiple `N`, `M`). Using `replace` also puts the before->after i.e. var->value mapping side by side, which I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, that's some scary regex voodoo there! : )

> - Is this technique of nested assertions valid? (i.e. looking behind during a lookahead?)

Yes, that is perfectly valid in most PCRE implementations I know of.

> - Is there a simpler regex-based solution?

I didn't spend too much time on it, but I don't quickly see how that could be simplified or shortened with a single regex replacement.

Comment: Any reference on your answer for part 1?

Comment: No reference. I just know it works because I've tried and used it in the past. Why shouldn't it be legal? I wouldn't know where to find a reference that told be I could use a group inside another one, I just know I can.

Comment: Regarding your voodoo comment: to fully understand something, you must not fear it =)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simpler regex-based solution?

It took me a while, but eventually I managed to simplify the regex to:

```
"(?=.{0,N}$(?<=(.{N}))).|." // repeatEnd
          -or-
".(?<=^(?=(.{N})).{0,N})|." // repeatBegin
```

Like Alan Moore's answer, this removes the negative assertion, but doesn't even replace it with a positive one, so it now only has 2 assertions instead of 3.

I also like the fact that the "else" case is just a simple `.`. I prefer to put the bulk of my regex into the "working" side of the alternation, and keep the "non-working" side as simple as possible (usually a simple `.` or `.*`).

Comment: When I mentioned needless use of negative logic, I wasn't referring to the negative lookahead *per se*, but to the contortions you went through to get that lone `.` all by itself in the second alternative.  That may seem clearer to you, but to my eye it has the opposite effect.

Comment: It's definitely a matter of personal preference. I'd always prefer `if(!a && b) X else Y` to `if (a) Y else if (b) X` when they're interchangeable (which they aren't always). In any case, I'd appreciate your input on `repeatBegin` I mentioned in the update to the question; I'm honestly having a hard time with it. I have a solution that works, but it's quite different from `repeatEnd`.

Comment: `"(?<=.{N}|^(?=(.{N})).{0,N})."` seems to work.  It's essentially the mirror image of my `repeatEnd` regex, except I had to use `{0,N}` instead of `*` to satisfy Java's "odious maximum length" requirement, plus `^` to force the lookbehind to go all the way back.