# codingBat separateThousands using regex (and unit testing how-to)

Tags: java, regex, unit-testing

This question is a combination of regex practice and unit testing practice.

#### Regex part

I authored this problem [`separateThousands`](http://codingbat.com/prob/p237587) for personal practice:

> Given a number as a string, introduce commas to separate thousands. The number may contain an optional minus sign, and an optional decimal part. There will not be any superfluous leading zeroes.

Here's my solution:

```
String separateThousands(String s) {
  return s.replaceAll(
      String.format("(?:%s)|(?:%s)",
        "(?<=\\G\\d{3})(?=\\d)",
        "(?<=^-?\\d{1,3})(?=(?:\\d{3})+(?!\\d))"
      ),
      ","
  );
}
```

The way it works is that it classifies two types of commas, the *first*, and the *rest*. In the above regex, the *rest* subpattern actually appears before the *first*. A match will always be zero-length, which will be `replaceAll` with `","`.

The *rest* basically looks behind to see if there was a match followed by 3 digits, and looks ahead to see if there's a digit. It's some sort of a chain reaction mechanism triggered by the previous match.

The *first* basically looks behind for `^` anchor, followed by an optional minus sign, and between 1 to 3 digits. The rest of the string from that point must match triplets of digits, followed by a nondigit (which could either be `$` or `\.`).

My question for this part is:

- Can this regex be simplified?
- Can it be optimized further?

  - Ordering *rest* before *first* is deliberate, since *first* is only needed once
  - No capturing group

---

#### Unit testing part

As I've mentioned, I'm the [author](http://codingbat.com/authoring.html) of this problem, so I'm also the one responsible for coming up with testcases for them. Here they are:

```
INPUT, OUTPUT
"1000", "1,000"
"-12345", "-12,345"
"-1234567890.1234567890", "-1,234,567,890.1234567890"
"123.456", "123.456"
".666666", ".666666"
"0", "0"
"123456789", "123,456,789"
"1234.5678", "1,234.5678"
"-55555.55555", "-55,555.55555"
"0.123456789", "0.123456789"
"123456.789", "123,456.789"
```

I haven't had much experience with industrial-strength unit testing, so I'm wondering if others can comment whether this is a good coverage, whether I've missed anything important, etc (I can always add more tests if there's a scenario I've missed).

Comment: What your asking is not necessarily unit testing. It is more of coverage tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
return s.replaceAll("(\\G-?\\d{1,3})(?=(?:\\d{3})++(?!\\d))", "$1,");
```

The first time through, `\G` acts the same as `^`, and the lookahead forces `\d{1,3}` to consume only as many characters as necessary to leave the match position at a three-digit boundary.  After that, `\d{1,3}` consumes the maximum three digits every time, with `\G` to keep it anchored to the end of the previous match.

As for your unit tests, I would just make it clear in the problem description that the input will always be valid number, with at most one decimal point.

Comment: @Alan: any significance to the possessive quantifier?

Comment: @poly: Not really.  It makes the lookahead infinitesimally more efficient, but the regex won't fail without it.  I just like to use them whenever I know indeterminacy is not in my interest.

Comment: @Alan: I haven't done any testing, but my gut tells me that my regex is faster since it doesn't use any capturing group, `\0` is empty, and the variable-length lookahead _first_ is needed less often (the more frequent _rest_ is simpler in comparison). Will do some testing and report tomorrow (need sleep).

Comment: @Alan: By the way, if it's not obvious from the recent developments, I no longer see regex as this magical flute to make beautiful (sometimes orgasmic!) music with. I now see it as just a tool, which is why I picked a more "real" example (separating thousands), and why I'm more concerned with performance etc rather than conciseness, elegance, and all that first love blindness stuff =)

Comment: @poly: If performance were a real concern, not using captures *could* make a significant difference--good point there.  And that would apply even if I had left out the parens and used `$0` instead of `$1`, which I could have done.  Most of the cost would come from parsing the group references and building the replacement string; I would expect that to dwarf any difference in *regex* performance.

Comment: @poly: As for the attitude progression: good on you!  But I hope you don't lose your enthusiasm completely; your solution to the `repeatEnd` problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606214/codingbat-repeatend-using-regex) was bloody brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

When you state the requirements are you intending for them to be enforced by your method?

> The number may contain an optional
>   minus sign, and an optional decimal
>   part. There will not be any
>   superfluous leading zeroes.

If your intent is to have the method detect when those constraints are violated you will need additional to write additional unit-tests to ensure that contract is being enforced.

What about testing for `1234.5678.91011`?

Do you expect your method to return 1,234.5678.91011 or just ignore the whole thing? 
Best to write a test to verify your expectations

Comment: These are good questions. I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do with unit tests. Right now, if the input is "invalid" (by whose definition, I'm not sure), I just scream "undefined behavior!". I'm not sure if that's the proper way to unit test. Maybe I should just read a book.

Comment: We're really just relying on the underlying RegEx engine to find the matching text and apply the transformation where appropriate. I guess the most important testing would ensure you don't malform text by adding commas where they don't belong.