# Examples of regex matcher \G (The end of the previous match) in Java would be nice

Tags: java, regex

Do you haven any useful example of the boundary matcher "\G"`? Please give me some **real world examples**. Java source is appreciated. From "Mastering regular expressions. Jeffrey E. F. Friedl" I got an useful example parsing HTML but I am not sure how if a translation to Java is possible.

Comment: I addressed a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14366062/211627

Answer (score 6):

This is a regex-based solution to introduce thousand separators:

```
String separateThousands(String s) {
  return s.replaceAll(
     "(?<=\\G\\d{3})(?=\\d)" + "|" + "(?<=^-?\\d{1,3})(?=(?:\\d{3})+(?!\\d))",
     ","
  );
}
```

This will transform `"-1234567890.1234567890"` to `"-1,234,567,890.1234567890"`.

#### See also

- [codingBat separateThousands using regex (and unit testing how-to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703689/codingbat-separatethousands-using-regex-and-unit-testing-how-to)

  - Explanation of how it works, and alternative regex that also uses `\G`.

---

This one is more abstract, but you can use `\G` and fixed-length lookbehind to `split` a long string into fixed-width chunks:

```
String longline = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (String line : longline.split("(?<=\\G.{6})")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
/* prints:
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx
yz
*/
```

You don't need regex for this, but I'm sure there are "real life" scenarios of something that is a variation of this technique.

Comment: That's very nice. I hope other authors will bring some more real world examples to the table.

Comment: I don't see the point of `"(?:%s)|(?:%s)"`? That should just be `"%s|%s"`.

Comment: @Christoffer: I was just playing it ultra-safe for the general case where "left" or "right" can have its own top-level alternation, but I think you're right: even in that case, it'll still work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Gfoo");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("foo foo");
    String trueFalse = m.find() + ", " + m.find();
    System.out.println(trueFalse);

    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("foo");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("foo foo");
    String trueTrue = m1.find() + ", " + m1.find();
    System.out.println(trueTrue);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where is the "real world" scenario?