# Split column in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am new to Hive and Hadoop framework. I am trying to write a hive query to split the column delimited by a pipe '|' character. Then I want to group up the 2 adjacent values and separate them into separate rows.

Example, I have a table

```
id mapper

1  a|0.1|b|0.2
2  c|0.2|d|0.3|e|0.6
3  f|0.6
```

I am able to split the column by using `split(mapper, "\\|")` which gives me the array

```
id mapper

1  [a,0.1,b,0.2]
2  [c,0.2,d,0.3,e,0.6]
3  [f,0.6]
```

Now I tried to to use the lateral view to split the mapper array into separate rows, but it will separate all the values, where as I want to separate by group.

### Expected:

```
id mapper

1  [a,0.1]
1  [b,0.2]
2  [c,0.2]
2  [d,0.3]
2  [e,0.6]
3  [f,0.6]
```

### Actual

```
id mapper

1  a
1  0.1
1  b
1  0.2 
etc .......
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to split your pairs `split(mapper, '(?<=\\d)\\|(?=\\w)')`, e.g.

```
split('c|0.2|d|0.3|e|0.6', '(?<=\\d)\\|(?=\\w)')
```

results in

```
["c|0.2","d|0.3","e|0.6"]
```

then explode the resulting array and split by `|`.

**Update:**

If you have digits as well and your float numbers have only one digit after decimal marker then the regex should be extended to `split(mapper, '(?<=\\.\\d)\\|(?=\\w|\\d)')`.

**Update 2:**

OK, the best way is to split on the second `|` as follows

```
split(mapper, '(?<!\\G[^\\|]+)\\|')
```

e.g.

```
split('6193439|0.0444035224643987|6186654|0.0444035224643987', '(?<!\\G[^\\|]+)\\|')
```

results in

```
["6193439|0.0444035224643987","6186654|0.0444035224643987"]
```

Comment: it works for the alpha numerics. but how to achieve if the input is like `split('10|0.2|20|0.3|30|0.6', '(?=\\w)\\|(?=\\w)')` will result in `["10|0.2|20|0.3|30|0.6"]`

Comment: @kars89 , I edited the answer, now it works for both cases.

Comment: Thanks @serge_k, I get the idea on what you are saying.
But I have the more than one digit after decimal marker and some how I am not able to deduce the required output.
My real world input is `"6193439|0.0444035224643987|6186654|0.0444035224643987"`.
or Can you provide me a pointer for where I  can look for the regex guide?

Comment: @kars89 , I changed the regex so it splits on the second `|`

Comment: Perfect @serge_k. works great. 
Could you please explain me the logic if possible, I am not able to grasp the regex.

Comment: So the core idea is in `\\G` -- the end of the previous match operator (specific for Java). Here is good examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708833/examples-of-regex-matcher-g-the-end-of-the-previous-match-in-java-would-be-ni . Basically, with negative lookbehind `?<!` and `G[^\\|]` we ignoring first ocurance of `|` and split on the second. Honestly I googled this regex once in the past and it works great.